# Avoiding scope pitfalls when breaking up Backbone.js set method?

Tags: javascript, model-view-controller, callback, closures, backbone.js

I'm using Backbone.js for MVC.

Inside my Model.set() method I'd like to wait for data to be loaded before triggering change events.

```
//Pseudo
set() {
   create changed attributes ... then:
   dataHelper.load(changedAttributes, stabilizeModel)
}

stabilizeModel() {
   now set changedAttributes on model ...
   ... and trigger change events
}
```

What would be a proper way for the stabilizeModel method to:
1) have access to the changedAttributes
2) have the correct scope (being called as a callback from the "dataHelper")

Comment: I am having a real hard time understanding exactly what you want to do.  Can you show us some actual code to illustrate the problem you are having?

Comment: I don't understand what you would load when a property of the model was changed. Please update the question with more details. It seems like you're potentially using it incorrectly.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you should be attempting to override model.set(). Instead you should just leverage it:

```
function load() {
    var attr_to_load = { ... }; 
    var attr = dataHelper.load(attr_to_load );
    this.set(attr);
}
```

I'd need more information to give you anything better.